# How to make all interface properties same type in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a slight problem with React.js/Typescript, I have declared the interface with specific interface properties, and all of them have the same type, how can I make everything simple without duplicating types in my interface, what will be the best approach?

```js
  export interface IinvestmentItemStyles {
    invsetmentContainer: React.CSSProperties
    invsetmentContainerHeaderStyle: React.CSSProperties
    invsetmentContainerHeaderTitleStyle: React.CSSProperties
    invsetmentContainerHeaderLabel: React.CSSProperties
    invsetmentContainerHeaderInfo: React.CSSProperties
    investmentDetailsContainer: React.CSSProperties
    investmentDetailsItemValue: React.CSSProperties
    investmentDetailsItemLabel: React.CSSProperties
    investmentActionContainer: React.CSSProperties
    investmentActionInput: React.CSSProperties
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use utility type Record

```
Record<string, React.CSSProperties>
```

or if you want to define properties names:

```
Record<'invsetmentContainer' | 'invsetmentContainer ' | ... , React.CSSProperties>
```

if properties names already defined in other type:

```
Record<keyof SomeType, React.CSSProperties>
```

Comment: ...you can even create mapped types, generating new names from existing names